# Laravel Passport API Response

Tags: laravel, eloquent, timezone

When I requested by Laravel Passport API then my datetime data has been changed like first Photo.
Second Photo is Laravel Model Casting.
Third one Photo is my table column.

How I get my original data without Laravel Mutator (Accessor)
I need always return my app timezone wise data with format Y-m-d H:i:s
Have any way to handle it easily?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Like below. It will solve your problem.

```
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
    'mobile_verified_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
];
```

Comment: what is the output? what about your birth output?